# Create a line chart using an user input table from a data table in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am taking user input  table created by user using java script to add data in it. I took the data from table and try to plot the chart using chartjs library but unable to plot chart .I have tried the following but I am getting canvas id with my first column of table. I am a bit stumped. Any help appreciated.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Index File</title   

</head>
 <body>
<script src="dist/js/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="POItablediv">
<p>
<input type="button" id="bt" value="Submit Data" onclick="submit()" />
</p>
<input type="button" onclick="insRow()" id="addPOIbutton" value="Add values"/><br/><br/>
<table id="POITable" border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>WEEK NO</td>
        <td>alpha</td>
        <td>beta</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>

    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
<canvas id="pieChart"></canvas>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function deleteRow(row)
    {
        var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        if(i>1){
        document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
        }

    }


    function insRow()
    {

        var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
        var len = x.rows.length;
        new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

        var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        inp1.id += len;
        inp1.value = '';
        var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        inp2.id += len;
        inp2.value = '';
        x.appendChild( new_row );
    }
   function submit() 
   {
     var table = document.getElementById("POITable")
     var tableLen = table.rows.length           
     var data = {labels: [], alpha: [], beta: []
   }

   for (var i = 1; i < tableLen; i++) 
  {
     data.labels.push(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText)
     data.alpha.push(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerText.replace(',',''))
     data.beta.push(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerText)
  }
    var canvasP = document.getElementById("pieChart")
    var ctxP = canvasP.getContext('2d')
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {type: 'line',
    data: 
    { 
        labels: data.labels,
       datasets: [{data: data.alpha,}]
    },
      options: {
      legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "right"
            }
            }
            });
             }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a problem with the procedure of getting values:
The values you are passing to the `data.alpha` and `data.beta` are from inputs and not the `td` element as your code shows:

```
<td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
<td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox"/></td>
```

And the mode of getting values won't work with input fields, you have to get the `value` and not `innerText` as you've done here:

```
data.alpha.push(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerText.replace(',',''))
data.beta.push(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerText)
```

You should use the following to get the value from the input:

```
data.alpha.push(table.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].value.replace(',',''))
data.beta.push(table.rows[i].cells[2].childNodes[0].value)
```

Using `childNodes` returns all the children of the parent element in this case the `td` tag. The `childNodes[0]` returns the first child of the parent element which is the `input` tag then the `childNodes[0].value` returns the value of the input field.

You can also replace this with the `datasets` you are using to get a more friendly output:

```
datasets: [{label: "Pie Chart", data: data.alpha, backgroundColor: "#138bc2", borderColor: "#777777"}]
```

The `label` will show beside the chart instead of the current `undefined` value which is showing.
The `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` are self-explanatory ;)

Comment: if i want to table fully user input based how can i make chart from it . and how to make chart taking values from data.alpha and data.beta like multiple charts . Please help me in this .

Comment: Do you mean you want stacked line graphs with multiple datasets, in this case from both data.beta and data.alpha

Comment: yup stacked line graph with multiple dataset..   and also need help to make table fully user based in my case week no is too user defined  . what changes i make in my code . please provide me the fiddle for this . i shall be very greatfull to u . thanks for responding me quickly .:)

Comment: I've prepared a pen for you to practice with, though here is an explanation of what has changed. ```datasets: [
          {label: "Alpha Data", data: data.alpha, backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 34, 123, 0.5)", borderColor: "#777777"},
          {label: "Beta Data", data: data.beta, backgroundColor: "rgba(123, 45, 4, 0.5)", borderColor: "#333333"}```. As you can see, you add multiple lines to a line chart by separating them with a comma. Also try experimenting ```type: line``` to ```type:bar``` which also uses same data .... [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/cypherjac/pen/yLYxXXv?editors=1010)

Comment: hi @cypherjac .. i just want to know how to render the same chart to different pages of html ?? secondly which visualization  library  is good for visualization charts ?? can u provide me good sources to learn java script l.. thanks in advance

Comment: For starters, the functions you've written: ```deleteRow()```, ```insRow()``` and ```submit()``` are reusable, so if you put the javascript in a separate file for example ```chartdata.js```, then link it from your different html pages it will work the same way provided you put the same ids and classes to the elements. As for me I use Chartjs which is simple enough and also customizable ... there are many chart plugins but for me I use chartjs cause it was my first to learn. And a good source which I use(d) is [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/) and also for reference

Comment: for my area i want to put table in one page and render chart to three different pages so how can i put the same chart to three different places by using clicking submit button .. one page is dedicated to table and by clicking submit button i can render chart to three different pages .. thanks for answering me  in advance

Comment: There are 2 ways to do that since you want the chart data stored somewhere then retrieved by other pages: **1.** You can implement a server-side language for example `php`, which requires a server that runs on a PHP backend, then use `GET` requests to capture the data which was submitted .. **2.** You can use [Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to use data stored in the different pages ... Also the best way to store the chart data, for both php and local storage, is in **JSON** format using `JSON.stringify`, then you can use `JSON.parse` to make it a Js object

Comment: can u please help me in second option  how can i use local storage to data storage and render the plot to different place . i am very great-full to u in  fiddle option . its very urgent ..

Comment: I actually don't use local storage myself and I can't put a fiddle on how to use it, that's why I put a link for you to understand it by yourself, just take a few minutes and understand how it works and you will be well on your way -- But the concept is that once you have saved the chart data in the local storage, it will be available for other pages to use; For example, this code from the link I sent above: ```var alphadata = //dataset here; localStorage.setItem("alpha", alphadata);
.. {label: "Alpha Data", data: localStorage.getItem("alpha"); ..``` Try understanding from the link first

Comment: hi @Cypherjac !! I stuck in one issue . i want to print my table in horizontal format below the canvas chart when i render my chart to some other pages but my table code doesnot work please look into consideration [https://codepen.io/humblefool15/pen/NWGoojX] please append me the changes

Comment: It says **404(Page Not Found)**, you can put up another one, I'll be glad to help you

Comment: ohh my bad ! please look into this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61968276/printing-json-in-html-table-saved-from-another-table-using-local-storage-so-that] i shall be greatful if u help me in this ...