# Printing JSON in HTML TABLE saved from another table using local storage so that i print my table on another page

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

In my assignment i have to take the data from user input using and save data in local storage. I have to print this data from local storage in horizontal table format to other pages.For this i made the code for user input and saving data in local storage

```
<style>
        data {
            color: #138bc2;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
   <div id="POItablediv">
   <p>
   <input type="button" id="bt" value="Submit Data" onclick="submit()" />
   </p>
   <input type="button" onclick="insRow()" id="addPOIbutton" value="Add values"/><br/><br/>
   <table id="POITable" border="1">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <td>WEEK NO</td>
           <td>Daily exercise</td>
           <td>calorie</td>
           <td>food</td>
            <td>Revision no</td>
           <td>Delete?</td>

       </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td><input size=25 type="text" id="weekbox"/></td>
           <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
           <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox"/></td>
           <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lnbox"/></td>
           <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lntbox"/></td>
           <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>

       </tr>
       <tbody>
   </table>
   </body>
   <script>
   function deleteRow(row)
    {
        var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        if(i>1){
        document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
        }

    }


    function insRow()
    {

        var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
        var len = x.rows.length;
        new_row.cells[0].childNodes[0].value = "";

        var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        inp1.id += len;
        inp1.value = '';
        var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        inp2.id += len;
        inp2.value = '';
        x.appendChild( new_row );
        var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        inp3.id += len;
        inp3.value = '';
        var inp4 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        inp4.id += len;
        inp4.value = '';
        x.appendChild( new_row );
    }
   function submit() 
   {
     var table = document.getElementById("POITable")
     var tableLen = table.rows.length           
     var data = {labels: [], alpha: [], beta: [],gamma:[]}

   for (var i = 1; i < tableLen; i++) 
  {
     data.labels.push(table.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0].value)
     data.alpha.push(table.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].value)
     data.beta.push(table.rows[i].cells[2].childNodes[0].value)
     data.gamma.push(table.rows[i].cells[3].childNodes[0].value)
  }
 var alphadata = data
localStorage.setItem("quant", JSON.stringify(alphadata));
```

above code is for taking input from user and saved in local storage .My aim is to print data from local storage to another page in  vertical header I mean that the table has the header () tag on the left side (generally).

```
e<body>
<input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
<p id="showData"></p>
 </body>

<script>
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
    var myBooks =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("quant"));

    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
        for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Table is not printing when i click on button in second page . its gives me blank page . Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: you deleted my answer in your old identical post. and you still use fuzzy vocabulary to explain your question. Why ?

Comment: i deleted the question @mister jojo . in this post i clearly mention my doubt why should i dont get my values in table . it it anything wrong in my code . logically it works . please accept my sincere apology  deleting my question . in this post i clearly mention my doubt

Comment: you should ask your questions separately for each technical difficulty you encounter instead of associating them all in a problem that you will never manage to articulate until you have mastered your subject

Comment: ok cool but my doubt is clearly mentioned that what the issue in this .. why my code is unable to populate the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code implements another function to create a horizontal format.
Please read the comments and also try to understand it so that it can help you in the future

```
<html>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="createHorizontal()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
    <p id="showData"></p>
    <div id="horizontal"></div>
</body>

<script>

    function createHorizontal(){
        var myBooks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("quant"));
        console.log(myBooks);

        col_keys = Object.keys(myBooks);
        // Object.keys gets the keys of the object
        col_values = Object.values(myBooks);
        // Object.values gets the values in an object

        var final_array = [];
        /* Here is the final array that will hold all the data */

        for(var i = 0; i < col_keys.length; i++){
            var inner = [];
            // The inner array that will be pushed with a new value
            // after every loop

            inner.push("<div class='main'>");
            inner.push("<li>" + col_keys[i] + "</li>");
            for(var j = 0; j < col_values[0].length; j++){
                inner.push("<li>" + col_values[i][j] + "</li>");
            }
            inner.push("</div>");

            //The above code creates the html for each of the rows

            inner = inner.join("");
            // To remove the commas from the final array
            final_array.push(inner);
        }
        console.log(final_array);

        var elem = document.getElementById("horizontal");
        var final_div = [];

        final_div.push("<div class='container'>");
        for(var n = 0; n < final_array.length; n++){
            final_div.push(final_array[n]);
        }
        final_div.push("</div>");

        // The above code creates the html for the whole div block

        final_div = final_div.join("");
        // To remove the commas
        console.log(final_div);

        elem.innerHTML = "";
        elem.innerHTML = final_div;
    }
</script>
<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        /* Make the rows stack on top of each other */
    }

    .main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        /* Make the elements in the div stack side by side */
    }

    .main li {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: 50px;
    }

    .main li:first-of-type {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

It also uses `CSS` to make the elements appear in that format or else it would look different. I advise you to analyze and understand it.

Comment: thanks@Cypherjac for a informative solution..Is there any way to print my chart data in table aligned to chart in chartjs library . my area of concern is to render chart  and print table below it so thats chart points are aligned to table data

Comment: If you are using a bar chart or a line chart -- Since the chart is rendered on a canvas, it has a defined width for example `<canvas I'd="mychart" width="500px" ... >`. So you can use the same width for your table and divide the width of the cells according to the number of data applied to them, for example if the size of your data is 5, then the width of each cell will be `100px` each and they will align with the chart which is also evenly spaced. You can also use add `labels` property to label the data for example `{ labels: ["data1", "data2"], datasets: [{ ... }] ... }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057166/how-to-display-table-from-chart-js-data-in-canvas-js-using-java-script? i asked the question here and test my logic in this way . please help me .  this is urgent for me  please :)

Answer (score 0):

So I did not find a problem with the first file that inserts the JSON data to the local storage. The problem was with getting the data from the second file

```
<html>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
    <p id="showData"></p>
</body>

<script>
    function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var myBooks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("quant"));
        console.log(myBooks);
        /* This logs the object to confirm whether it is there and to 
        confirm the values inside it You should make this a habit
        so that you can check for errors*/

        // var col = [];
        // for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
        //     for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
        //         if (col.indexOf(key) == -1) {
        //             col.push(key);
        //         }
        //     }
        // }
        /* The code above is the one I have commented out and replaced with
        the one below to get both the keys and values in separate arrays */

        col_keys = Object.keys(myBooks);
        // Object.keys gets the keys of the object
        col_values = Object.values(myBooks);
        // Object.values gets the values in an object

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        /* --- REFERENCE 1 --- The length of col_keys and col_values is the same because they
        are key and value pairs */

        for (var i = 0; i < col_keys.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col_keys[i];
            /* col_keys has the keys of the object which are added to
            the table header */
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.

        for (var i = 0; i < col_values[0].length; i++) {

            /* The loop runs as many times as the number of items in each array
            EXPLANATION: col_values contains arrays.
            col_values[0].length returns the length of the first array, which is
            the array that contains the labels.
            And since all the arrays have the same length whether they have a value
            or not, the length of the first array is the same for all the others. 
            --- REFERENCE 2 --- In this case this outer loop runs 2 times*/

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col_values.length; j++) {
                /* The inner loop runs as many times as the number of key-value pairs
                in the object.
                EXPLANATION: As " --- REFERENCE 1 --- " above says, this will run **4** times
                based on your current object which has:
                1.labels
                2.alpha
                3.beta
                4.gamma
                */
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = col_values[j][i];
                /* Each time the loop runs, it inserts the "i" value of the array
                of each of the values of the object.
                Check " --- REFERENCE 2 --- " ... since "i" is less than the length
                of each array, it will only run as many times as the number of values
                in the array.
                In this case **2** times.
                */
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

There are comments everywhere so make sure to read them and understand why it works that way. Because this is also a learning process. If you have a question just ask.

Comment: thanks @cypherjac i want to make the header in vertical manner so that data in each header  move row wise

Comment: Here's a tip, since you have the `col_keys` and `col_values`, you can create another array for example `final_array` then create a for loop that runs 4 times: (**the length of either of the above arrays**), then inside the final_array, (which will be an array of arrays) , for example for the **first** array - append the **first** value of the `col_keys` array then append the **first** value of the `col_values` array which is also an array ...  so in this case you will be appending the values of the array and not the array itself. Then you can append the values of the `final_array` to the table

Comment: Another option is changing the approach of displaying the data and choose for instance a `div` block with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` and inner `div` blocks with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` and you will not need a table header, just add the elements inside their own div block and they will have a horizontal direction

Comment: can u provide me fiddle for second method . first i will done by my self