# how to display table from chart js data in canvas.js using java script .?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

In my projects i  need  to make my chart more responsive . I print table from chartjs data using  too but i got garbage value in table . any other method is also appreciated

```
var ctxP = canvasP.getContext('2d')
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {type: 'line',
    data: 
        { 
            labels: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("label")),
            datasets: [
      {label: "DFT", data: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dft")), borderColor: "ORANGE",fill: false,markerType: "triangle"},
      {label: "FUNCTIONAL", data: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fun")), borderColor: "GREEN",fill: false,markerType: "circle"}
    ]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "right"

            }
        }
    });

addTable(myPieChart);

        function addTable(myPieChart){
                              var tableData = "";
                             for(var i = 0; i < myPieChart.data.datasets.length; i++)
                             { 
             tableData += "<tr>" + "<td style='color:" + myPieChart.data.datasets[i].borderColor + 
                            "'>&#9632;" + myPieChart.data.datasets[i].label + "</td>";
              for(var j = 0; j < myPieChart.data.datasets[i].data.length; j++){
                      tableData += ("<td>" + myPieChart.data.datasets[i].data[j].length +"%</td>")
                         }

                      tableData += "</tr>";
                        }
                 $("#chartData").append(tableData)
                   }    
              }</script>
```

Comment: Exactly what data is being used in the local storage for `dft` and `fun`? Please provide the code for the `localStorage.setItem()` that you are using to help us to so we can understand and help you better

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61968276/printing-json-in-html-table-saved-from-another-table-using-local-storage-so-that/61974899?noredirect=1#comment109759245_61974899] in this  one i am taking data from userinput and saved the data to plot charts so that i render  it to different places  but i need table too so i used upper code to plot chart and table  in  a more responsive way

Answer (score 0):

So, what was the error you were getting and what did you expect from the code? Please also provide that, other than that, this code here:

`tableData += ("<td>" + myPieChart.data.datasets[i].data[j].length +"%</td>")`

is adding the length of the data and not the data itself, remove the `.length` to get the actual data:

`tableData += ("<td>" + myPieChart.data.datasets[i].data[j] +"%</td>")`

Comment: Thanks bro i got the data . but my table and chart is not aligned to each other

Comment: i want to aligned the table and plot chart data in sync manner

Answer (score 0):

This is the same `addTable()` function with a few changes:

```
function addTable(myPieChart) {
    var tableData = "";
    var data_size = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < myPieChart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
        tableData += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < myPieChart.data.datasets[i].data.length; j++) {
            tableData += ("<td>" + myPieChart.data.datasets[i].data[j] + "%</td>")
        }
        tableData += "<td style='color:" + myPieChart.data.datasets[i].borderColor +
            "'>&#9632;" + myPieChart.data.datasets[i].label + "</td>";
        // Notice how I have swapped the labels with the data
        // Because your legend is also on the right
        tableData += "</tr>";
    }
    $("#chartData").append(tableData);
    data_size = $('#chartData').children('tr:first').children('td').length;
    // Get the size of the data in the table
    $('#chartData').children('tr').children('td').css({
        // This 500 is the width of the canvas element that holds the chart
        // This code makes the width of the cells responsive
        width: 500 / data_size
    });
}
```

Also this option makes the chart scale according to your needs:

```
options: {
    //set responsive to false
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "right"
    }
}
```

You can also add this `CSS` to make it close to what you expect, but this is the closest it can get because they have different structures.
**They cannot possibly align perfectly.**

```
#chartData td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also try experimenting with more `CSS` styles and see the outcome